# call a generator (that may not terminate) a fixed number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, generator

is there a more pythonic way to call a generator (one that may or may not terminate) a specific number of times?

for example: if i want to call `endless` exaclty `N = 7` times i could to it this way:

```
from itertools import count, accumulate

N = 7
endless = accumulate(count())
for _, out in zip(range(N), endless):
    print(out)
```

what i do not like about that is that it is a bit error-prone (changing the order of `range` and the generator will call the generator `N+1` times) and that i need to handle the output from `range` (which i do with the `_` variable).

Comment: `itertools.islice`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks! just figured that out as well...

Answer (score 0):

oh, i just may have found a possible answer to that myself:

```
from itertools import islice, count, accumulate

N = 7
endless = accumulate(count())
for out in islice(endless, N):
    print(out)
```

(...should i delete the question?)

Comment: Regarding deletion - generally no, the duplicate is useful as it is a different way of wording the same question, so it will occur in web searches